# Most appropriate data structure to save reflection data

Tags: java, data-structures, reflection

What would be the most appropriate data structure to save data collected using reflection? I would like to reflectively collect various data about classes (Java) and store them inside some kind of data structure, so later this data can be used. Example of collected data would be Modifiers, fields, methods, relations...

Thank you

Comment: The answer to "how should I store X data" is "it depends on what you're doing with it". Do you need to sort it by name? A tree or array makes sense. Do you need to access it by some identifier? A map or tree makes sense. Do you need to easily access fields/methods/etc related to other fields/methods/etc? A graph makes sense. Determine what you're trying to accomplish (which operations you'll be using the most - insert, delete, update, read, sort, etc) and choose data structures that are best at what you're trying to accomplish. The type of data (reflection data) might not matter at all.

Comment: @Welbog thank for the answer. This requires more in depth research and possibly go through some examples.